# Handling firmware with many copies of the same code/data in different address spaces

Tags: firmware, ghidra

When loading the firmware I am working with, it copies multiple regions of code/data to another write-able memory region.

I normal load the code/data into the destination location and leave the source empty. But have just noticed the firmware calls some of the functions in the original/source region.

So I could leave all of the source data/code and load the duplicate data/code regions, but what I am wanting to avoid is duplicated reverse engineer the functions.

So what I ideally want is someway to alias/memory map the regions so there is only "one" version of the memory, thus one labeled data and RE functions.